# python3 read data from csv file and covert it into json

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

this is my code covert json into csv.

```
import csv
import json
with open('Documents/SampleCSVStory.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    data_list = list()
    for row in reader:
        data_list.append(row)
data = [dict(zip(data_list[0],row)) for row in data_list]
data.pop(0)
s = json.dumps(data)
print (s)
```

but the output coming like this

```
[{"Id,Name,Description": "1,User 1,Python Developer"}
```

my expectation is

```
[{"Id:"1",Name:"User 1",Description:"Python Developer"}
```

can anyone helping me in this please.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import json

with open('Documents/SampleCSVStory.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
json.dumps([row for row in reader])
```